# Force Synergy To Use My Own Covers

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, synergy, album-art

I use [Synergy](https://wincent.com/products/synergy) to display a floating cover/title/artist/album/year floater on my screen. There's one behavior that's particularly frustrating to me I've never found a way around. Is it possible to force it to use the track's cover for the artwork display? It seems that it only uses my own if it can't find it on Amazon, but in actuality, I always prefer my own cover to Amazon's hit-or-miss quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a known issue between Synergy 4.5 and iTunes when running in 64-bit mode](https://wincent.com/issues/1844). Make sure that you're running iTunes in 32-bit mode using the toggle in the "Get Info" panel for the iTunes application:

[image: Screencaputre of iTunes in 32-bit mode]

Or, upgrade to Mac OS X 10.8 and [Synergy 5.0a or later](https://wincent.com/blog/synergy-5.0a-release).

Switching iTunes to 32-bit mode corrected this problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I dont understand the question?..... i use synergy and it uses my own album covers

> If the tracks in your iTunes music library already contain embedded art then Synergy will use that artwork. Note that there are some limitations to that feature; namely it only works for locally-stored music files (iTunes doesn't export album covers for music that is playing across the network via shared playlists, for example).

[(Source)](http://wincent.com/a/products/synergy-classic/album-covers/)

Comment: You're right, their documentation does say that's the way it's supposed to work. I guess it's a bug.

Comment: maybe a re-install is in order

Comment: It's most likely a 64-bit mode issue. Switching iTunes to 32-bit mode fixes this for me.